# 301 htacces doesnt work on Magento 2

Tags: magento2, htaccess

I place my code at the top of htacces, but it doesn't work. What did i do wrong?

```
# Redirect [CODE] [OLD PATH] [NEW PATH]
RewriteEngine On
Redirect 301 /sieraden /dames/dames-accessoires.html
```

page: http://schoenen-data.eu/dames/dames-accessoires.html

Comment: As per your code   http://schoenen-data.eu/sieraden should redirect to http://schoenen-data.eu/dames/dames-accessoires.html, When checked it is redirecting.

Comment: Yes i'ts working fine now! Changed the code a bit.

Comment: Good to know that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the code a bit, and now it works fine!

```
# Redirect [CODE] [OLD PATH] [NEW PATH]
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?sieraden$    /dames/dames-accessoires.html [L,R=301]
```